# segmentation fault at value assignment in C

Tags: c

Hello I am learning C and tried to write code that will compare 3 numbers and tell me which one is the biggest.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int max(int a, int b){
    if(a > b){
        return a;    
    }
    return b;
}
int main()
{
    int a, b, c;
    printf("Please provide the first number --> ");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("Please provide the seceond number --> ");
    scanf("%d", &b);
    printf("Please provide the third number --> ");
    scanf("%d", &c);
    int big = max(max(a, b), c);
    printf("The biggest number is --> ");
    printf(big);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I wrote it on a website called onlinegdb.com but after I input the 3 numbers I get a segmentation fault error after trying to find what was wrong it showed me that there seems to be a problem with inserting the result of max into big

Comment: If you do not see error messages for `printf(big);` then change compiler settings or use a different compiler

Comment: you can Also use https://godbolt.org/ 
I personally found it very convenient .you will get an opportunity to select the compiler of your choice and can optimize the o/p as well.

Comment: If you really want to use a numeric format string... you could do `unsigned format = 0x0a206425; printf ((char*)&format, big);` but that is just using a numeric equivalent for the character string `"%d \n"` (where the space (`0x20`) is necessary to prevent the nul-character that would result from `0x0a006425`)

Answer (score 4):

I think it might be due to this line of code

```
 printf(big);
```

try using:

```
 printf("%d", big);
```

basically you forgot to put the format specifier.

Answer (score 1):

The first argument to printf is the format string followed by any values

```
printf("%d\n",big);
```